# MongoDB - Tag based search with autocomplete

Tags: mongodb, performance

I am looking to implement a tag search feature and was looking for some advice in terms of efficiency. I am new to MongoDB so I am unsure of best practices for performance.

Okay so I want to create a link sharing app which users tag the links based on their content. For instance a funny dog image would be tagged with "funny" and "dog". A link would have a:

```
 title, 
 url, 
 user_id, 
 tags: array of tags
```

Now in order for me to allow users to search for links I need a list of all the tags used. For usability this needs to have auto-complete functionality. So I researched a bit and tested out using a collection of tags where I index the tag value e.g. "funny" and then use a regex.

```
 db.tags.find({value:/^search/})
```

With a collection of 600,000 documents it searched for all documents beginning with "s" in 63 milliseconds. As the length of the search term increases the execution time decreases.

Now comes the part I'm unsure of. Say for instance I want to find all the links with have the tags "funny" and "dog" (need to use intersects). How should I store the tags? Should I store the object id of each tag? Can I index these object ids? Is there another way to structure the whole database?

Also id like to be able suggest tags based on tags they already entered. I was thinking of just having a related field in the tag document for instance:

```
tag
----
id
value
related: [{
   tag_id
   count
}]
```

(again unsure as it would suggest tags that could be related to one of the already entered tags and not to another. With an intersect this would return no results.)

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Edit: mistake

Comment: With your current data model and potentially storing the IDs of tags and related tags... Have you considered "$setIntersection" aggregation queries? Or is that what you meant by "use intersects." I think you are on the right track by storing tags in a separated collection each with a list of related tags.

Comment: Yes sorry that's what I mean. I guess I could do I set intersection of all related tags which would work.

Answer (score 1):

Create a text index on the tag array. This will enable you to search quickly for funny, dog, and funny or dog.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/

```
db.tags.createIndex( { tags: "text" },  {background:true}  )
```

As to the related tags, I don't think that you want to reference the _id values. You can probably embed an array of related tags such as:

```
relatedTags: [{tag1}, {tag2}]
```

Comment: Given there is 600k documents you might want to do background true on the index creation. 

   db.tags.createIndex( { tags: "text" }, {background:true} )

Comment: Thanks. I will look into. I didn't know while indexes were being built no read write operations could be performed.

Comment: Yeah! One of the more frustrating things I've done in the past. Locking reads for an index which takes an hour to build is scary.

Comment: Very true, create the index in the background. I updated the answer.